# Changing <td> value

Tags: jquery, html-table

I want to change the value of all `<td>` to empty when their value is `0`.

I already tried:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('td[value="0"]').val('');  
});
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if ($('td').val()==0
    {
        $('td').val('');
    }
});
```

But neither works.

http://jsfiddle.net/s46ty/

Comment: Is `value` some custom attribute you use on the `TD`? Because `value` is not a valid attribute on a `TD`-element.

Comment: I know TD's don't have a value as attribute, i just tried it baceuse i've already done that to inputs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/s46ty/6/)

```
$('td').filter(function(){return $.trim(this.innerHTML) === "0"}).text('');
```

Comment: what if TD text equal 01234

Comment: @GaneshRengarajan I only want to set it to empty if it's content is 0,  not anyother value

Answer (score 4):

Change

`$('td').val()` to `$('td').text()` or `$('td').html()`.

`$.val()` only works on things that have a value, such as inputs.

Here is a working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/ApWWY/1

Comment: It's not working properly for me here. Check this please http://jsfiddle.net/s46ty/1/

Comment: You're using $.text() as a setter. Please clarify what you want to do.

Comment: First of all, you forgot to embed jQuery in that fiddle, and then you want to _read_ the value, not set it, and then compare it (and you want to compare it to `' 0 '`, because there are spaces around the 0 in your td - or trim the value first) - http://jsfiddle.net/s46ty/3/

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use the attribute `value` on your `TD`-element, use the following instead (for setting the value)

```
$('td[value="0"]').prop('value', '');
```

Please note that `value` is not a standard-attribute for a `TD`-element.

Comment: TDs don't have value attribute nor property

Comment: @roasted I know. But you can use it as a custom attribute (Not always a good idea, but it works)

Answer (score 0):

This one should work

```
$('td').each(function () {
  if ($(this).text() == 0 || $(this).text() == '0') {
    $(this).text('');
  }
});
```